# Search icon is missing in the site switcher

Tags: bug, design, search, top-bar

The search icon is missing in the top bar menu, before the "Find a Stack Exchange community" placeholder.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Search icon not available in MSE]

---

Where as the search icon is available in the stackexchange.com and Area 51 top bar menu.

> [image: Search icon available in SE.com]